# Keep all messages in Console

Tags: logs, console

On macOS High Sierra (10.13.6), Console.app automatically trims old messages when it exceeds 50000. Significance: When I'm searching for specific keywords or processes, after I select the relevant messages, the first message is deleted, therefore the whole view is refreshed, removing the selection. This happens about once each second, and it's very annoying.

How can I stop this behavior? Is the only option to export all logs to an log archive and open it in Console? But it's really slow and that way I won't get newer messages.